# How to take output of this function and use it as a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

code

```
data = 'address'
print(data.id)
```

when i run this code it will print the following output

```
(('instance', u'id 123456789'),)
```

how to make this output into a dictionary like this

```
{"id":"123456789"}
```

Comment: how can print dataa.id give that output ? data is not a dictionary! you need to show your data object

Comment: im asking to convert this `(('instance', u'id 123456789'),)` into a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = dict([data.id[0][1].split()])
```

Where `data.id` is: `(('instance', u'id 123456789'),)` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
k, v = (('instance', u'id 123456789'),)[0][1].split()
d = {str(k) : str(v)}
print(d)
```

I should output this

```
{'id': '123456789'}
```

To have them as unoce strings take the str(..) out. (in python 3.x unicode is the same as str

Comment: This doesn't return a dictionary tho

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like...

```
res={} #initialize dictionary
res['id']=id(data)
print(res)
```

Result :

> {'id': 1754862887072}

Other than this...

```
print(data.id)  # will throw error, str does not have id property
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> out = (('instance', u'id 123456789'),)
>>> a,b = list(out).pop()
>>> dict([str(b).split()])
{'id': '123456789'}
```